# Strange behaviour on MFC Thread

Tags: multithreading, while-loop, mfc

I'm new here, but always found help in the past.
I'm facing a strange problem with a simple block of code:

```
UINT ThreadMain(LPVOID pParam)
{
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    THREADDATA*     pData           = (THREADDATA*) pParam;
    INT*            pnEditBoxValue  = pData->pnEditBoxValue;
    UINT            nEid            = pData->nEditId;

    PLC *parent = (PLC*)pParam;
    bool trigger_basso = false;
    m_thread_running = 1;
    CDeCoMotorDlg* wnd = pData->pObjDlg;

    while(m_keep_alive==1)
    {
        SleepEx(1, 0);
        wnd->CheckDlgButton(nEid, TRUE);
    }
    m_thread_running = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem seems related to this line:

```
wnd->CheckDlgButton(nEid, TRUE);
```

The lines works well (a check box is set on the gui), BUT, if I press a button on my GUI that sets the

```
m_keep_alive = 0
```

then the function stop working immediately: I don't see the while loop terminating properly and I never reach this line:

```
m_thread_running = 0;
```

What's strange is the if I remove this line

```
wnd->CheckDlgButton(nEid, TRUE);
```

the while loop exits properly, the flag is set and the thread exit properly...
I'm getting crazy...any suggestion?

Many thanks

Comment: Given this fragment of code, I can only make guesses. Maybe you have another piece of code that sets `m_keep_alive` back to 1 (triggered by that `wnd->CheckDlgButton(nEid, TRUE);`). Also, have you checked if the thread is actually run multiple times? Also, synchronizing threads using global variables (talking about `m_keep_alive` and `m_thread_running`) is not recommended, you should instead use synchronization objects (or put everything into critical sections). Furthermore, windows should best be accessed/changed from their owning threads.

Comment: *"Strange behavior"* in C++ almost exclusively means: Undefined behavior. Accessing data from more than one thread concurrently without synchronization results in undefined behavior. You are also casting `pParam` to pointers to different types. This, too, exhibits undefined behavior (unless you're lucky enough to hit one of the exceptions).

Comment: _" the function stops working immediately"_: what does that mean exactly? You need to elaborate on this.